Route53 IPv6 Outbound Resolver not forwarding
I can't seem to get Route53 to correctly forward DNS requests to nat64.net when using IPv6. The host in this case is Ubuntu 22 (though I think this is about AWS).
Here's the background:

I've created a Route53 Outbound Resolver with interfaces in an IPv6-only subnet. The "Resolver Endpoint Type" is "IPV6".
The security group associated to the interfaces allows all outbound and all inbound from within the VPC.
I created a Resolver Rule to forward requests for ghcr.io to the three IPv6 addresses found on nat64.net
The Resolver Rule is associated to the VPC.
I can successfully query one of the IPv6 addresses on nat64.net from an IPv6-only EC2 instance within the same subnet as the Outbound Resolver endpoints. In other words, this works:

$ nslookup ghcr.io 2a01:4f9:c010:3f02::1
Server:     2a01:4f9:c010:3f02::1
Address:    2a01:4f9:c010:3f02::1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ghcr.io
Address: 140.82.121.34
Name:   ghcr.io
Address: 2a01:4f9:c010:3f02:64:0:8c52:7922
Name:   ghcr.io
Address: 2a01:4f8:c2c:123f:64:5:8c52:7922
Name:   ghcr.io
Address: 2a00:1098:2b::1:8c52:7922



This also works (showing DNS generally is fine within the VPC and that the subnet has Internet access via an IGW):

$ nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.211.238
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:400a:807::200e


This does not work. I think this shows that the resolver rule is working but that the Outbound Resolver isn't contacting the nat64.net addresses.

$ nslookup ghcr.io
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; no servers could be reached


VPC flow logs don't show any rejected connections
Reachability Analyzer doesn't work with IPv6 (link)

I have not (yet) found any documentation stating that Resolvers can't use the Internet. I'd love to hear the community's thoughts on this!
Update 1
I installed BIND9 on an EC2 instance inside the IPv6-only subnet and created a Route53 Rule to forward requests for ghcr.io to it and that works fine—the Outbound resolver seems to successfully resolve when using BIND9 as a proxy. I have not yet figured out why the Outbound Resolver's IPv6 endpoints can't seem to directly connect to the IPv6 addresses outside the VPC when the EC2 instance in the same subnet can do so.

The way I read this AWS Doc is that traffic from the outbound endpoints cannot go through an Internet Gateway. So I have IPv4 traffic going through a NAT gateway - but you can't do this for IPv6 - and it doesn't seem to work through an egress-only internet gateway.
So I think you've hit on the only current solution for IPv6 - (ie setting up a 'local' resolver in the VPC).
